# What happens if you inline a function that calls it self in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

First I thought the compile time would take forever, or I take a weird error, but that didn't happen. The code runs for a while and then crashes.

This is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

inline void say_hello()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    say_hello();
}

int main()
{
    say_hello();
}
```

I thought the compiler will convert it to something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    // and crash because my storage is filled
}
```

But, I think the compiler ignored the `inline` keyword.

Comment: In modern C++ the `inline` keyword is at best a hint to the compiler that you might like the function to be inlined. It isn't binding and shouldn't be used for this optimization. Compilers are smart enough to know when a function should be inlined, and the absence of `inline` does nothing to prevent it. `inline` is basically only used to get around ODR.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux is it possible to force the compiler to inline a function?

Comment: Obviously, the compiler will not inline forever. In this particular case, it could have warned against the infinite recursion. At best, a compiler could inline the function on one or a few levels (if that made sense), then switch to a plain function.

Comment: Just to say, you crashed because you overflowed the stack.

Comment: @NightmareXD You'll need to use a compiler intrinsic for that, which is not portable. Additionally, these will usually be ignored if the function is recursive.

Comment: @PaulSanders Oops, missed that part.

Comment: *But I think the compiler ignored the inline keyword*  I think you may be misinformed as to what the `inline` keyword means in C++.

Comment: @fran NP, it happens :)

Comment: Compile that code at -O2 and I would be shocked if the obvious tail-recursion didn't completely optimize out to iteration, and just turn it into a flat infinite loop. And for bonus points, inlined into `main` easily thereafter. E.g. [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/nxPEG4qGh)

Comment: My understanding is that recursion is one attribute that cancels the `inline` benefits.  I would expect that the compiler creates a single instance of the function (as if it is ignoring the `inline` request).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern C++, the `inline` specifier is only a suggestion to the compiler that you might want to inline the function. The compiler is not required to comply.

For your specific compiler, please see [Visual Studio Inline Functions (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=msvc-170). You seem to "want" the `__forceinline` decorator combined with `#pragma inline_recursion(on)`. This will inline to a depth of 16, but that is modifiable as well. I hope it's obvious why this is all a bad idea. Note that this is ALL compiler specific and does not apply to gcc.

`__forceinline` can fail for a variety of reasons, but the ones that might apply to you:

- the function is recursive (what you have) and `#pragma inline_recursion(on)` is not set
- the program is compiled with `/Ob0` (the default for debug builds, which you might have set)

If you want to recurse to a level different than 16 (the default), you can use the [`inline_depth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/inline-depth?view=msvc-170) pragma to specify.

Your function would end up looking like this (untested):

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma inline_depth(9000)
#pragma inline_recursion(on)
__forceinline void say_hello()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    say_hello();
}

int main()
{
    say_hello();
}
```

Comment: Now my program doesn't crash, but the executable size isn't big as I expected I also used ```#pragma inline_depth(999999)``` to increase the depth, but I didn't notice any changes I also compiled it in release mode, but I get a warning that says **warning C4717: 'say_hello': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow** so I think it ignored the ```__forceinline``` keyword but why it didn't crash this time?

Comment: @NightmareXD Your function is tail-recursive, so the compiler can optimize it into a loop – the equivalent of `void say_hello() { start: std::cout << "hello\n"; goto start;}`. That can easily be inlined and becomes very small.